# Is there any way to have a text file on the server be readable only by the browser?

Tags: webserver

I have a few pages on my web server that extract data from text files that each contain a JSON string. The pages use $.get

Is there any way to allow only the server/webpages access the files? I would prefer to not have people going to the file path and saving the JSON data to their computer.

If I set permissions to deny access to the default IUSR, then people visiting the site won't be able to load them.

Any tricks around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put such files in a directory tree out of the one the web server can see. e.g., html pages accessible by the browser go into /var/www/public_html/filename.php, but files that should not be seen go into /var/privateFiles/anotherfile.txt. The web server root is /var/www - so the web server cannot see anotherfile.txt, but filename.php can include it using full path name.